# How to exclude particular scenarios in BDD using QAF BDD2 framework?

Tags: bdd, qaf

I have a feature file containing multiple scenarios, few of them are manual. When I run my scenarios I want to exclude Manual scenarios. How to exclude Manual scenarios using QAF BDD2?

```
Ex: Feature Hello
@channel.. @run
Scenario: Run this scenario
Given ...
When ..
Then..

@Manual
Scenario: Exclude this scenario
Given ...
When ..
Then..
```

When I run this, it picks all scenarios and skips the one with have @Manual tag saying no def found which is valid but I dont want this scenario to run and skip. I want to exclude this scenario, I tried adding exclude tags in config xml file like  below it did not work.

```
<groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="Manual"></exclude>
            </run>
        </groups>
```

Comment: Can you share your xml config file?

Answer (score 0):

it should work with qaf latest version. As alternate you also can try using [meta-data filter](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario_metadatata_filter_include_exclude_prop.html) providing exclude property instead of groups tag. For example:

```
<parameter name="exclude" value="{'groups': ['Manual']}" />
```